# Youtube Video id by using Service account - got error 403 response

Tags: java, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I’m developing Java code to retrieve Video Id for the corresponding asset id by using service account authentication.I have followed below mentioned steps.
Step 1: A Java program is written to retrieve the access token from Google authentication using service account.
the code is for getting access_token:

```
    String EmailId = "XXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

                         //passing Scope
                         @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
                           List<String>scops = new <String>ArrayList();
                           scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

                         final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
                      final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

                  // Create a listener for automatic refresh OAuthAccessToken
                   List<CredentialRefreshListener> list = new ArrayList<CredentialRefreshListener>();
                   list.add(new CredentialRefreshListener() {
                         @Override
                       public void onTokenResponse(Credential credential,
                               TokenResponse tokenResponse) throws IOException {
                           System.out.println(tokenResponse.toPrettyString());

                       }

                       public void onTokenErrorResponse(Credential credential,
                               TokenErrorResponse tokenErrorResponse)
                               throws IOException {
                           System.err.println("Error: "
                                   + tokenErrorResponse.toPrettyString());
                       }


                   });
                         GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                         .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                         .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                         .setServiceAccountId(EmailId)
                         .setServiceAccountScopes(scops)
                         .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("test.p12"))
                         .setRefreshListeners(list)
                         .build();
                  credential.refreshToken();
```

Step 2: The access token that is obtained in step 1 is passed as an argument in the below mentioned URL to get Youtube video id

Sample url is:

- https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claimSearch?assetId=xxxxxxxxx&onBehalfOfContentOwner=xxxxxxxx&status=active&access_token=ya29.-gCmzBHciDghrj2EDtBn1Vx0MV38pNLZTvqfwOyG0hNJCj75nsCBA5zaxmP1sr7UqI7ZrYI3AIZstA
  I’m getting 403 error code in step 2.

  ```
  {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
     {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
      "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
      "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
     }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
  }
  }
  ```

  already enabled “GOOGLE COULD JSON API” and “YOUTUBE DATA API”.
  Could any one please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know from working on a previous project that you need to enable the API in the Google console. I would try that first.

https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: Hi Alan,Thanks for ur reply.already i enabled "youtube data API v3" and "youtube analytic api",rather these two i didnt find any APIS

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct service account that has the APIs turned on against as the error suggest you don't

Comment: i didnt find the youtube Content API in my account,but it asking me the same API i guess

Comment: In this URL it showing "youtube content API"-https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claimSearch/list,but coming to MY project API list it not showing any

Answer (score 0):

You try to use Youtube's Content ID API endpoint /youtube/partner/v1/claimSearch.

This endpoint is not part of the Youtube Data API and you can only access it if you participate in the "Youtube Partner Program". Otherwise it is not even listed in the Developer's Console.

Further information here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/

> Note: The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by YouTube content partners and is not accessible to all developers or to all YouTube users. If you do not see the YouTube Content ID API as one of the services listed in the Google Developers Console, see www.youtube.com/partner to learn more about the YouTube Partner Program.

Comment: Hi Larry,thanks for ur reply,even i m trying with youtube partner account,but got different expection like 404 error.

Comment: For me the query is working. But, if i type in the wrong Name or Id of the onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter, i get a 404 as well. 

{ error: { errors: [ { domain: "global", reason: "notFound", message: "The content owner that you are trying to act on behalf of cannot be found. Check the value of the <code>onBehalfOfContentOwner</code> parameter to ensure that it is correct.", locationType: "parameter", location: "onBehalfOfContentOwner" } ], code: 404, message: "The content owner that you are trying to act on behalf of cannot be found. ...." } }

Comment: i added "behalfofcontentowner" in my url,now i got 500 error:{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtubePartner",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "An internal error has occurred."
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "An internal error has occurred."
 }
}

Comment: Actually the param name is "onBehalfOfContentOwner"

Comment: Hi larry,this is my URL:https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/claimSearch?assetId=A871664583627609&onBehalfOfContentOwner=obzLhUWEzl0ZQow3XlHMXQ&status=active&access_token=ya29.AAGQVh4jtX_isx6FUJQUHxkDue706FX-7amEHm2Z2QihD15PKCOiPdpU3VtRTFIzz8h1tSekMKuD7Q

Comment: Well thats strange. If i replace your params with mine the query works pretty fine.

Comment: Strange behaviour, if i lookup the connected ContentOwners for the accessToken, i get two duplicated entries: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/contentOwners?fetchMine=true&access_token=ya29.AAGQVh4jtX_isx6FUJQUHxkDue706FX-7amEHm2Z2QihD15PKCOiPdpU3VtRTFIzz8h1tSekMKuD7Q Your 500 Server error could be related to this. By the way, you should not copy and paste accessTokens to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Thanks larry,I m looking on this..but i dont knw hw to resolve this

Comment: Can't help you either, this looks like a case for the support. Or maybe check the account settings of the user or ask the admin/contentOwner if he sees something suspicious.

Comment: hi larry,you are using service account for authentication to generate access_token?

Comment: I used a regular google/youtube account to create the app that generates the access_token. Later on i got the contentOwner privileges and activated the Content Partner API for the previously created App.

Comment: tht correct larry,but which way ur using to generate access_token.i.e service account flow or server side flow.plz find the below url:https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/auth

Comment: Got it, i use server side flow with offline token_access

Comment: If u dont mind could you share some sample code for me to follow

Comment: Wich part? The complete application is very complex and written in php ;)

Comment: oh..for me its required in Java..any how thanks larry for ur reply